# Proving that every Hölder-continuous function with an exponent $\alpha>1$ is constant.

Tags: analysis, continuity

A function $f$ is called Hölder-continuous on the interval $I$, when there exist a constant $C$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and an exponent $\alpha>0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\alpha$$ for every $x,y$ in $I$.

What is to be proven is that if $f$ is Hölder-continuous with $a>1$, $f$ must be constant.

What I have found out so far:

I need to show that
$$a>1 \iff f(x)=f(y)$$ for all $x,y$ in $I$.

After dividing the inequation by $|x-y|^\alpha$ I have

$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{\alpha-1}}\leq C$$

Is there a way to deduct that there is no constant $C$ such that this inequation can be satisfied except when the numerator is $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|}\leq C|h|^{\alpha-1}$$

Now use squeeze theorem.

Comment: I.E show the derivative is $0$ at every point and then use mean value theorem.

Comment: Just for clarity: I let $h \rightarrow 0$ and show that the value of the derivative approaches 0 for all $x$ in $I$?

Comment: @B.Schnebbler The value of the derivative is exactly $0$ for all $x\in I$, yup!